# Best way to explain popup blocking to users and have them allowed?

Tags: web-app, popup, older-users

I'm working on a web application that uses a pop-up to display the window where the users input their credit card details and pay. This, of course, is preventing MANY users from doing do so because of automatic pop-up blocking from most browsers. Cart abandonment is pretty big.

No, the pop-up isn't necesary and the whole company is well aware of the problems it causes, but right now there's nothing we can do to go around it. I'd explain why (tech limitations and "strategic" alliances with financial services providers) but it's beyond the point. We just have to use the pop-up right now...

Our client base is pretty old and/or not very tech savvy, so this makes the problem even worse. I'm strugglind to find an effective way of showing them how to allow pop ups, besides a video tutorial.

Can you think of any good examples or practices to deal with the problem, UX-wise?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of what the popup looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Actually what you wrote is a common problem that I also come across as a user. If you are based in Singapore, Malaysia or India, you may come across this NETS service which is an online payment service. This online payment service requires users to allow pop-ups in order for their payment verification to go through.

One service provider I remember do a good job of preparing users to "brace ourselves" for the pop-up which is necessary in order to carry out the transaction. I remember vaguely it's either one or 2 steps before the pop-up, there is a glaring message on the top side of the webpage which says, "In order for the payment processing to go through, please allow pop-ups in your browser before continuing to the next steps."

And at that stage the webpage actually allows users time and space to work on the browser settings before continuing (e.g. lack of countdown timer on check out, having a clean interface, etc.).

I'll post a screenshot of that interface the next time I use it.